# Defining variable in Mariadb

Tags: mariadb, declare

I tried a lot of ways to use user defined variables in MariaDB version 10.3.22. After failing to use it in my application, I wanted to try with a simple example:

```
DECLARE @EmpName1 NVARCHAR(50)
SET @EmpName1 = 'Ali'
PRINT @EmpName1
```

gives Unrecognized statement type. (near "DECLARE" at position 0)

After some digging around I tried using it between delimiters and as a created function:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION test
DECLARE @EmpName1 VARCHAR(50)
SET @EmpName1 = 'Ali'
PRINT @EmpName1 
END //
DELIMITER;
```

This gives

1. Unrecognized data type. (near ")" at position 54)
2. A "RETURNS" keyword was expected. (near "END" at position 110)

I cannot figure out where the issue might be coming from, as the MariaDB documentation has the same syntax as far as I can see.

Can anyone help solving this issue? My final goal would be to assign the single result of a query to a variable as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few syntax matters:

1. Need a `()` set after the function name, even if no parameters are used:

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION test()
   ```
2. A function's return data type must be specified after that: (I used the same type/size as your variable. Can be some other type, of course, depending upon what is being returned)

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION test() returns varchar(50)
   ```
3. The use of `@` with the variables not needed, also missing `;` at the end of each line, plus `PRINT` is invalid:

   ```
   DECLARE EmpName1 VARCHAR(50);
   SET EmpName1 = 'Ali';
   -- PRINT EmpName1; see item 4
   ```
4. Functions are expected to return a value:

   ```
   RETURN EmpName1; -- I simply replaced the PRINT with RETURN here.
   ```

Putting that all together, the complete definition becomes:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION test() RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
    DECLARE EmpName1 VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';
    SET EmpName1 = 'Ali';
    RETURN EmpName1;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Then after that is created, use the function:

```
SELECT test();
```

Example interaction:

```
root@localhost(test) DELIMITER //
    ->     CREATE FUNCTION test() RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
    ->     BEGIN
    ->         DECLARE EmpName1 VARCHAR(50);
    ->         SET EmpName1 = 'Ali';
    ->         RETURN EmpName1;
    ->     END //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

root@localhost(test)
root@localhost(test)  DELIMITER ;

root@localhost(test) select test();
+--------+
| test() |
+--------+
| Ali    |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.09 sec)
```

Though the website does not use `DELIMITER` you can also see this in action at [this DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=a1d790b261d940b9abd354c7e3c4af04).